# Keeping div the same without refresh when changing pages

Tags: javascript, php, html, navigation, refresh

I am looking for a way to have a navbar on my website, that doesn't refresh / reload / flicker when I change from *home.php* to *page1.php*. Currently my navbar is included in both home and page1 from *nav.php* using a JS fade in script.

Comment: Use AngularJS for view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Ajax** to do that. Suppose you have this kind of layout structure

```
<header>
<!-- Your navigation can be here -->
    <ul class="your-navigation">
        <li class="your-navigation__item"><a uri="link-to-home-page-content">Home</a></li>
        <li class="your-navigation__item"><a uri="link-to-page1-content">Page1</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>

<main>
<!-- Your content here -->
</main>
```

Then your Javascript could look like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="link-to-jquery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      function changeContent($uri){
          var $parent = $('main');
          $.ajax({
              url:$uri,
              type:'get',
              success:function($content){
                  $parent.html($content);
              },
              error:function(err){
                  # You can handle errors like 404, etc from here
              }
          });
      }

      $('.your-navigation__item').click(function(){
           changeContent($(this).attr('uri'))
      })
  });
<script>
```

I hope that was helpful, happy coding :)